# RAD Environment for C? (Not C++, just C)

Tags: c, rad

I want to do RAD with C, but the only ones I can find only use C++.

Comment: If you want to do RAD perhaps you should consider C# or Java. C is the opposite of RAD. Great low level language but you'll never get RAD out of it.

Comment: Sure you can:  just copy and paste a suitable application!

Comment: If you want to be really rapid, go for a high level language like Python, Perl or Ruby.

Comment: If there is a RAD that can use C++, it can also use C. Well written C tends to be legal C++ also.

Comment: @Vijay Mathew: yes, but not the opposite. Most RAD libraries for C++ make heavy use of classes and in some cases templates, that are completely absent in C.

Comment: To do RAD in C write yourself a REPL (read-eval-print-loop) for C

Comment: Define "RAD" for the purpose of this question. I have a feeling it's not exactly the conventional definition.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/), a UI designer for GTK+.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to define what you expect when you use the term RAD.  Technically is is a methodology agnostic of language (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development, to understand what I mean).

If you mean "visual development" (which is the context in which it is applied to tools such as Delphi and C++Builder, primarily as marketing buzzwords and because Microsoft had already essentially trademarked "Visual" with respect to development tools), then use of C would require an application framework and tool to support this.  There is a reason why such tools are usually implemented with object-oriented languages; it is a much more natural fit for GUI elements.  This being the case, a tool vendor would be unlikely to choose C as the basis for such a tool.

Also it may be useful to understand what platform(s) you wish to target.

A judicious bit of Googling threw up a couple of things that may fit your requirements:

- [Auto-C](http://autoc.wolosoft.com/)
- [MGui](http://web.tiscali.it/morello/MGui/)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really understand why there only seemed to be OOP oriented languages with visual development tools, but now I do. I think I'm going to continue learning C and learn C# on the side.

Answer (score 0):

You may use BCX DevSuite Pro. It comes with GUI Designers that produces BCX code. When you compile BCX code, it produces also C code.